# how to use one image for few ImageViews?

Tags: android, image, imageview

Is there a way in android wich i can add just a part of an image to an imageview?
the reason i'm not cropping the original image is because i want to use the same image for several activities but each activity should have another part of the image.

Comment: extend BitmapDrawable and override draw() and getIntrinsic*() methods

Comment: why do people downvote this question? is something wrong with it?

Comment: maybe because you accepted the insufficient solution below?

Comment: all of these downvotes was there before this guy answered and why is it insufficient ?

Comment: because you create a copy of the source Bitmap

Comment: and why is it bad?(i'm new to programming)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can save the cropped image into a new bitmap so you keep the original image uncropped:

```
Bitmap croppedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(originalBitmap, x, y, a, b);
```